# Sony Camera Remote API, Liveview streaming slow

Tags: python, camera, sony, sony-camera-api

I'm using trying to stream live view of a SONY FDR-X1000V camera on desktop. I use python to call the API and download the package and use opencv to decode jpeg. 
When I run it, it can hardly catch one frame per second. Later I found out that the payload size of a jpeg can be 8MB. However, FDR-X1000V doesn't support changing live view size. But when I use the app on iPhone to do the liveview, it streams smoothly. So here is my question:
1. Is it normal that a jpeg payload can be as large as 8MB?
2. If so, how can I smoothly stream the live view?

Here is my code:

```
try:
    result = api.do('startLiveview')
    url = result['result'][0]
except KeyError:
    print result
f = urllib2.urlopen(url)
buff = ''
chunk_size = 32768
for i in xrange(3000):
    if len(buff) < chunk_size:
        time_s = time.time()
        buff = buff + f.read(chunk_size)
        print "Download Speed %f KB/s"%(chunk_size/1000/(time.time() - time_s))
    time_s = time.time()
    start_code = ''.join(buff).find('$5hy')
    # print "LCS time cost", time.time() - time_s

    if start_code < 0:
        buff = buff[-12:]
        print "skip", len(buff)-12
    elif start_code < 8:
        buff = buff[8:]
    else:
        if start_code > len(buff) - 129:
            buff = buff + f.read(chunk_size)
        payload_type = ord(buff[start_code-7])
        payload_size, = struct.unpack('<I', buff[start_code+4:start_code+8].ljust(4,'\0'))
        padding_size = ord(buff[start_code+8])
        print "Type:%d\tPayload:%d\tPadding:%d\t"%(payload_type,payload_size,padding_size)

        buff = buff[start_code+128:]
        if payload_type == 1:
            if payload_size + padding_size > len(buff):
                time_s = time.time()
                download_size = payload_size+padding_size-len(buff)
                buff = buff + f.read(download_size)
                print "Download Speed %f KB/s"%(download_size/1000/(time.time() - time_s))
            img_data = buff[:payload_size]
            buff = buff[payload_size:]

            time_s = time.time()
            d = np.asarray(bytearray(img_data), dtype='uint8')
            img = cv2.imdecode(d,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
            cv2.imshow('postview',img)
            cv2.waitKey(30)
            # print "Decode time cost", time.time() - time_s
```

Some output:

```
Type:1  Payload:8410624 Padding:0   
Download Speed 679.626326 KB/s
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from @Simon Wood and @Robert - Sony are all very useful!
I made two mistakes in my code.

One is the payload size is 3 bytes instead of 4 bytes.

Another is that I assumed the byte order is little-endian instead of big-endian.

The project mentioned by @Simon Wood is a good one. Although it doesn't implement resynchronization on the 4-byte start code.

To make this right, I write my own codes in two methods to check and resynchronize it:

```
try:
    result = api.do('startLiveview')
    url = result['result'][0]
except KeyError:
    print result
f = urllib2.urlopen(url)

#method 1
buff = ''
chunk_size = 8192
for i in xrange(300):
    if len(buff) < chunk_size:
        time_s = time.time()
        buff = buff + f.read(chunk_size)
        # print "Download Speed %f KB/s"%(chunk_size/1000/(time.time() - time_s))
    time_s = time.time()
    start_code = ''.join(buff).find('$5hy')
    # print "LCS time cost", time.time() - time_s

    if start_code < 0:
        buff = buff[-12:]
        print "skip", len(buff)-12
    elif start_code < 8:
        buff = buff[8:]
        print "skip a header"
    else:
        if start_code > len(buff) - 129:
            buff = buff + f.read(chunk_size)
        start_byte = ord(buff[start_code - 8])
        payload_type = ord(buff[start_code - 7])
        sequence_num, = struct.unpack('>I', buff[start_code - 6:start_code - 4].rjust(4,'\0'))
        time_stamp, = struct.unpack('>I', buff[start_code - 4:start_code].rjust(4,'\0'))
        payload_size, = struct.unpack('>I', buff[start_code+4:start_code+7].rjust(4,'\0'))
        padding_size = ord(buff[start_code+8])
        print "StartByte:%d\t sequenceNum:%d\t timeStamp:%d\t Type:%d\t Payload:%d\t Padding:%d\t"%(
            start_byte,sequence_num,time_stamp,payload_type,payload_size,padding_size)

        buff = buff[start_code+128:]
        if payload_type == 1:
            if payload_size + padding_size > len(buff):
                time_s = time.time()
                download_size = payload_size+padding_size-len(buff)
                buff = buff + f.read(download_size)
                # print "Download Speed %f KB/s"%(download_size/1000/(time.time() - time_s))
            img_data = buff[:payload_size]
            buff = buff[payload_size:]

            time_s = time.time()
            d = np.asarray(bytearray(img_data), dtype='uint8')
            img = cv2.imdecode(d,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
            cv2.imshow('postview',img)
            cv2.waitKey(10)
            # print "Decode time cost", time.time() - time_s

#method 2
def checkbyte(f):
    if f.read(4) == '$5hy':
        return
    state = 0
    i = 1
    while 1:
        i+=1
        if state == 0 :
            if f.read(1) == '$':
                state = 1
            else:
                state = 0
        if state == 1 :
            if f.read(1) == '5':
                state = 2
            else:
                state = 0
        if state == 2 :
            if f.read(1) == 'h':
                state = 3
            else:
                state = 0
        if state == 3 :
            if f.read(1) == 'y':
                state = 4
            else:
                state = 0
        if state == 4 :
            print 'skip', i
            return
for i in xrange(300):
    buff = f.read(8)
    start_byte ord(buff[0])
    payload_type, = struct.unpack('>I',buff[1].rjust(4,'\0'))
    sequence_num, = struct.unpack('>I',buff[2:4].rjust(4,'\0'))
    time_stamp, = struct.unpack('>I',buff[4:8])

    #payload header
    checkbyte(f)
    buff = f.read(124)
    payload_size, = struct.unpack('>I',buff[0:3].rjust(4,'\0'))
    padding_size= ord(buff[3])

    print "StartByte:%d\t sequenceNum:%d\t timeStamp:%d\t Type:%d\t Payload:%d\t Padding:%d\t"%(
            start_byte,sequence_num,time_stamp,payload_type,payload_size,padding_size)
    d = f.read(payload_size)
    if padding_size > 0:
        f.read(padding_size)

    if payload_type == 1:
        # Type = 0x01
        d = np.asarray(bytearray(d), dtype='uint8')
        img = cv2.imdecode(d,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
        cv2.imshow('postview',img)
        cv2.waitKey(1)

print api.do('stopLiveview')
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit of shameless promotion - but it might help you out. Did you try with pysony code?

You'll have to manually set the QX_ADDR but this should give you a 'faster' liveview stream...
https://github.com/Bloodevil/sony_camera_api/issues/22

The pygameLiveView example has the building blocks needed, you'd just need to tweak the jpeg loading to pull into openCV instead of pygame

Comment: I tried that `pysony`, however, they don't implement resynchronization on the 4-byte start code. That may lead to errors in practice.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue may that you are parsing “Payload data size without padding size” in “LiveView’s Payload Header” as 4bytes of data instead of 3byte bytes of data. So in this case payload size looks larger than expected. This is explained in the documentation under "**Format of the liveview data JPEG container**". Try changing this and let me know if it still does not work for you.

Comment: Yes, you're right, but the most important thing that doesn't mention in the document is about little-endian and big-endian. Here in my code, I assumed it's little-endian which caused most things doesn't work. An interesting fact is that, even though I miss calc the payload size(which is always larger than real size), OpenCV can always decode the image, which makes me believe the payload size is right.